# How can i solve FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a field's value in the doc of firestore collection. But its giving me this error.

> "FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore"

Heres my code

```
const Post = ({ name, description, message, photoUrl, like, id }) => {

    const usersCollection = collection(database, 'posts');
    const searchQuery = query(usersCollection, where(documentId(), '===', id))

    const handleLike = async () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const update = await updateDoc(doc(searchQuery), {
            like: like + 1,
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="Post">
            <div className="post__header">
                <Avatar />
                <div className="post__info">
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="post__body">
                <p>{message}</p>
            </div>

            <div className="post__buttons">
                <span onClick={handleLike}>
                    <InputOpntion
                        Icon={ThumbUpOffAltIcon}
                        title="Like"
                        color="gray"
                        like={like} />
                </span>
                <InputOpntion
                    Icon={ChatOutlinedIcon}
                    title="Comment"
                    color="gray" />
                <InputOpntion
                    Icon={ShareOutlinedIcon}
                    title="Share"
                    color="gray" />
                <InputOpntion
                    Icon={SendOutlinedIcon}
                    title="Send"
                    color="gray" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`updateDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#updatedoc) functions takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as a parameter and not a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query). Since you already have the ID of document you are trying to update, there's no need to fetch the documents with a query first and then update those. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const usersCollection = collection(database, 'posts');

// Create DocumentReference to that post document
const docRef = doc(usersCollection, id);

const handleLike = async () => {
    // Pass the DocRef here
    const update = await updateDoc(docRef, {
        like: like + 1,
    })
}
```